# Realms doesn't show in MCPE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

I'm on Minecraft Pocket Edition 0.7.6, and even though it says I'm logged in on home screen, when I enter the app Realms doesn't come up.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have access to Realms or the button will not be there.

Source: I have another account without Realms.

Answer (score -4):

Because your account isn't invited to any Realms server. Ask the owner of a Realms server to invite you.  I asked someone who has realm and he invited me, so ask the owners of Realms servers.